# Создание метода с аргументом колеекции Set, который содержит объекты, которые типизированны

Tags: java, generics

Всем привет!
Мне надо преобразовывать результаты валидации формы, которые представленны классом `java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<dox.web.dto.RegisterFormDTO>>`, где `dox.web.dto.RegisterFormDTO` одна из моих форм, требующая валидацию. Для этого я создал некоторый метод

```
public static void process(Set<ConstraintViolation<RegisterFormDTO>> validates) {
  ...
}
```

который, собственно, и производит преобразования. Но, проблема в том, что у меня кроме `RegisterFormDTO` есть ещё много других разных форм, и хотелось бы сделать один универсальный метод, который бы преобразовывал результаты валидации для их всех, тем более что работа с самой формой внутри метода не подразумевается. Сами формы ни от какого другого класса не расширяются, то есть просто Object, и логично было бы сделать так:

```
public static void process(Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validates) {
  ...
}
```

но, почему-то это не прокатывает, возвращает ошибку:
`java: incompatible types: java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<dox.web.dto.RegisterFormDTO>> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<java.lang.Object>>`.
Я уже пробовал и так `Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Object>>`, что тоже самое, и так `Set<ConstraintViolation<? super Object>>`. Всё это не прокатывает. В результате у меня получается, что я для каждой формы создаю один и тот же метод, отличающийся только типом в аргументе метода.
Может кто подскажет, как сделать метод универсальным для всех форм?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри `process` вообще никак не используются особенности `RegisterFormDTO`? Если да, то можно определить generic-метод:

```
public static <T extends Object> void process(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validates)
```

Что эквивалентно просто:

```
public static <T> void process(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validates)
```

Но это возможность принять параметр, большой вопрос в том, что с ним дальше делать.

Comment: BccHnw Отлично, то что нужно. Спасибо большое.